# Return values from an array based on dynamic array of keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array of keys and I want to iterate of them and return their corresponding values.

Generally, I know, I can just do a `object.key_name` or `object[key_name]` but I have a dynamic array and will populate with different keys.

Data:

```
data = [{hello: 'abc', asd: '123', fgh: '345' }, 
{hello: 'sdf', asd: '456', fgh: 'df' }, 
{hello: 'ty', asd: '789', fgh: '345675' },
{hello: 'qwe', asd: '123', fgh: '987' }]
```

array format: `arr = ['asd', 'fgh']`

I am trying to do: `let x = data.map(o => arr.map(strs => o[strs]));`

Result:

```
["123", "345"]
["456", "df"]
["789", "345675"]
["123", "987"]
```

Is there any way for me to get:

```
["123", "456", "789", "123"]  <= array for asd
["345", "df", "345675", "987"] <= array for fgh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of your map calls - first iterate the `format` array, and then extract the values from the `data`:

```js
const data = [{"hello":"abc","asd":"123","fgh":"345"},{"hello":"sdf","asd":"456","fgh":"df"},{"hello":"ty","asd":"789","fgh":"345675"},{"hello":"qwe","asd":"123","fgh":"987"}]

const format = ['asd', 'fgh']

const result = format.map(f => data.map(o => o[f]))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there!
You just need to start with the array of the keys:

```
arr.map(key => data.map(o => o[key]));
```